# task based sequence manager in c# for Unity3D

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asynchronous, unity-game-engine

**Note:this question should have been written on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ since it refers to Unity3D development (nothing to do with c# Unity Framework)**

I need a simple (single thread) library that allows to run sequences of asynchronous tasks that could last over the time (usually using yield).

in actionscript I used to use http://www.dpdk.nl/opensource/running-tasks-in-order-with-a-task-based-sequence-manager which was a great task sequencer.

Is there something similar in c#?

N.B.: while the system.threading.task class seemed a good solution initially, Unity 3.5 does not support .net framework 4. The version I can use is 3.5. Are there alternatives?

Comment: Did you really research this question before asking?  Did you search online for "C# task" and look through the results?

Comment: in actionscript I don't believe it supports native threading or true asynchronous calls, so when you move to c# you should not try to restrict yourself in the same way. they are different languages...

Comment: first, I said I do not want multithreading, second if you do not know actionscript please do not assume wrong things. What I asked is languague indipendent as long as it support asynchronous calls that in c# I want to achieve through the yield keyword and not multithreading. Beside I could do the same using green threading/time slicing.

Comment: @foson until now, I did not know what the task concept was in c#, so no, obviously I could not search for something I do not know. Although to be honest google made me find it, but at glance it seemed overcomplicated for what I needed. Luckily there are useful people like justin helping out.

Comment: Not sure why this question got such negative feedback, I had a similar one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I created my own system, I blogged about it here: http://www.sebaslab.com/svelto-taskrunner-run-serial-and-parallel-asynchronous-tasks-in-unity3d/

Answer (score 4):

You want to take a look at the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). This library can be used for multi-threading or not, so it is fairly robust. In fact, it is what the next version of .NET's `async/await` keywords are built on. I will write a quick code snippet shortly.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<String>(
               ()=>
               {
                   //Do some long running task
                   return "Here are my results from part 1";
               })
           .ContinueWith<Int32>(
               (previousTask)=>
               {
                   var previousResult = previousTask.Result;
                   //Do some other long running task using the previous result
                   return 1;
               });
```

There is A LOT that you can do with the TPL. This is just a general idea.

Also, there is the [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword for iterators, but that is not necessarily asynchronous.

Comment: I use c# in Unity3D and unity3D exploits the yield keyword to simulate asynchronous calls. It is doable and it is not that bad (in pratice it yields an IEnumerable routine until a given condition is met). I now flag the answer as correct, but I need to check more about it. It looks promising though.

Comment: just to be clear: I will try to create a task that yield a given operation. So the task must finish when the yield operation ends.

Comment: @sebas You could use the BackgroundWorker class, and just open a new BackgroundWorker on the previous one's completion. This is messy, but I believe it is the only solution without the TPL.

Comment: thanks Justin, I believe i could implement my own very simple version relying only on yield and IEnumerable,IEnumerator. As I said at begin I do not need multithreading and so I do not need all this complexiti, although the Task class looked good

Comment: @sebas Oh yah, forgot about that part...yah yield could work...maybe even a nested yield...but it would get complicated

Comment: I managed to do it with a simple stack structure :) Thanks anyway for your help, I will have a look at the task pattern once Unity will update mono version ;)

Comment: This answer is misleading because at the time being, Unity3D does not support that level of .Net platform so you cannot use Task Parallel library in Unity.